# How can I create mailto links without recipient that will work on Chrome on Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, mailto

I have a mailto link in my HTML. The HREF is

```
<a href="mailto:?to=&body=AAA,&subject=BBB">MAIL</a>
```

In other words, I am specifying body and subject, but not recipient.

In Chrome on Ubuntu, clicking this produces an dialog with a error

```
Unable to detect the URI-scheme of "mailto:?body.....
```

Note that Firefox opens Thunderbird correctly for the same link.

How do I code this link so it works?

Chrome 34.0.1847.137
Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Chrome 34.0.1847.137
Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: @JoshuaFox Is this still an issue in Ubuntu or this works fine now on newer versions? I don't have Ubuntu to test.

Answer (score 44):

If I understand the definition right this should work:

```
<a href="mailto:?to=&body=AAA,&subject=BBB">MAIL</a>
```

At least it does work in Chrome 36 on OSX…

[RFC 6068: The 'mailto' URI Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068)

Comment: Thank you. That is indeed what I have and it does not work. Note that Firefox opens Thunderbird correctly for the same link.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest to file a bug for the linux version of Chrome 34… If Firefox **and** Chrome 36 on OSX does understand the link (and as its fine to the RFC) it is an application issue…

Comment: The same problem occurs on Chrome on Windows.

Comment: This works fine on Windows. Chrome version 35.0.1916.114 m on Windows 7 Professional SP1

Comment: So then it looks like the issue has already been filed and is fixed with Chrome 35… Maybe also on Linux…

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a space between `mailto:` and `?body=AAA,&subject=BBB` like this:

```
<a href="mailto: ?body=AAA,&subject=BBB">mail link</a>
```

Or even adding [the space as Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm) like this:

```
<a href="mailto:%20?body=AAA,&subject=BBB">mail link</a>
```

Comment: I tried both. Both produced the same error as without the space.

Comment: The version with a `%20` space works for me (and also with outlook).

Answer (score 0):

What about
`<a href="mailto:?to=%20&body=AAA,&subject=BBB">mail link</a>`